# Do you need to put an Endpoint for each peer in Wireguard?

Tags: networking, wireguard

Let's say there's 3 peers in a network. A and B know each other's IP addresses, but C knows only A's IP address. So, in the config of A, it specifies an endpoint for B, but not C. In the config of B, it specifies and endpoint for A but not C. In the config of C, it specifies a endpoint for A, but not B. Can B and C still connect to each other, if they both know A?

Comment: A will need IP forward for C then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. First, `sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` and `sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT`. Two, and this is important, remove any mention of C from B, and B from C. It should be working now.